# Git - how to unignore a file

Tags: git, gitignore

Long story short, I accidentally added a file to .gitignore, which I committed and pushed.

Now I removed the file from .gitignore, but it's still not visible.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: did you commit the changes to .gitignore?

Comment: You still need to stage the file during your next commit, and stage the .gitignore file as well.

Comment: Yes, I staged and committed the new gitignore.

Comment: I did that, I have hidden files enabled and removed the file from my .gitignore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm stupid, it was left in global gitignore, which is why it wasn't showing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to recover that file from repository and commit it again:

```
git checkout 35fbd83 -- path/to/your/file
```

`35fbd83` is SHA of a commit where that ignored file was still present.

```
git add path/to/your/file
git commit -m 'missing file is back'
```

After a file is added to `.gitignore` its not tracked anymore. If you accidentally or purposely remove that file while it's ignored, git won't complain and that file silently disappears from your file system. Commands like `git reset --hard` and `git checkout` could lead to a situation where ignored files are removed from your working directory.